# 2 Components in 1 Controller

Tags: cakephp, components, requesthandler

Hi I am really new in CakePhp, I hope you can help me

```
    class BookingsController extends AppController {

    public $helpers = array("PDF");
//public $virtualFields = array(
// 'full_name' => 'CONCAT(Customer.cust_fname, ", ", Customer.cust_fname)'
//);
    public $components = array('RequestHandler');

    public $components = array('Search.Prg');

    public $presetVars = array(
        array('field' => 'search', 'type' => 'value'),
    );
/**
```

My question now is that I need $components in both. Is there any way to merge it together? Or how can I call both request handler and search.prg? I hope u can help

Comment: It looks more like you're new to php or at least OOP in php when you try to declare two properties with the same name. So before trying to use a framework that is heavily using OOP you might learn that first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply merge the arrays

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler', 
                           'Search.Prg', 
                           'OtherComponent', 
                           'ExtraComponent' /*etc*/);
```

Cake is smart enough to get what you mean. Also works for `$helpers` and `$uses`... and I guess pretty much everything really. You need to keep an eye on [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#configuring-components), it says clearly how to do what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler', 'Search.Prg');
```